Extremely slow playback speed Geometry nodes using large collection (+20000 instances)
I have a large collection of individual instances +20000 (not sharing the same object data), which are animated using geometry nodes. The issue is that when animating all instances at once, the playback speed becomes extremely slow (between 3-4 FPS) which makes the animation work very difficult. It doesn’t seem to be a hardware issue (since I have a pretty good PC config see below). I’ve read in a forum that playback animation speed and computing geometry nodes is a single-threaded process (so that is why it’s not utilizing my CPU fully I guess). Is it still the case today with the latest blender updates?
One option I found to increase FPS, is to split the main collection into a separate smaller collection and animate the collections using multiple geometry nodes to achieve the same result. What are the reasons behind it and do you have other optimization ideas to increase FPS?
Here are my specs:
13th Intel core i9 - 13900KF
128 gb memory
2x GPU Nvidia RTX 4090
Many thanks for your answers and help!

Are you realizing instances in your GN tree at any point or are you leaving them as instances? If you are realizing them then that will absolutely tank performance.
